# How to get actual URL to my Symfony (1.4) app?

Tags: php, symfony1, routes

I've configured my routing.yml with my route:

```
    users:
      url:      /users
      param:    { module: user, action: list }
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to, while processing request, access '/users' (actual URL) instead of 'user/list' (currentInternalRequestUri).

```
    var_dump( $request->getParameterHolder() ); //in controller
```

presents also 'pattern' field, but is is protected, so I can't access it from the outside.
Is there some method of obtaining current url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try

```
var_dump($request->getPathInfo())
```

Comment: I've probably checked everything except this one. Thanks a lot!